# how to parse a multidimensional array?

Tags: json, multidimensional-array

I want the key and value of the following multidimensional array with key :followersperdate

{"version":"1.2","username":"LGUS","url":"http://t.co/ospRRVboge","avatar":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000016800237/3787f02f0e0e10a0a19d9b508abd6ce2_normal.png","followers_current":38775,"date_updated":"2013-11-15","follow_days":"774","started_followers":544,"growth_since":38231,"average_growth":"49","tomorrow":"38824","next_month":"40245","followers_yesterday":37232,"rank":"14934","followersperdate":{"date2013-11-15":38775,"date2013-11-05":37232,"date2013-11-04":37126,"date2013-10-26":36203,"date2013-10-10":34384,"date2013-10-02":33353,"date2013-09-18":30870},"last_update":1384679796}

Comment: There are no multidimensional arrays in JSON.

Comment: Depends on the language you are using. All popular languages have JSON support, built-in or via libraries. And JSON is JSON, it doesn't matter how many nested arrays/objects you have, JSON is always parsed the same way. See at the bottom of http://json.org/ for a list of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

i cleared it for you, the object you want, has 7 sub objects, that can parse base on your language,
check this web page to learn more, choose your language, at the bottom of the site:
http://www.json.org/

if you are on a javaScript, check this http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp

```
{
"version": "1.2",
"username": "LGUS",
"url": "http://t.co/ospRRVboge",
"avatar": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000016800237/3787f02f0e0e10a0a19d9b508abd6ce2_normal.png",
"followers_current": 38775,
"date_updated": "2013-11-15",
"follow_days": "774",
"started_followers": 544,
"growth_since": 38231,
"average_growth": "49",
"tomorrow": "38824",
"next_month": "40245",
"followers_yesterday": 37232,
"rank": "14934",
"followersperdate": {
    "date2013-11-15": 38775,
    "date2013-11-05": 37232,
    "date2013-11-04": 37126,
    "date2013-10-26": 36203,
    "date2013-10-10": 34384,
    "date2013-10-02": 33353,
    "date2013-09-18": 30870
},
"last_update": 1384679796
}
```